# Loop won't execute in Microsoft Visual Studio ASM

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

Use a loop instruction with indirect addressing to reverse the elements of an array in place.

- Do not copy the elements to any other array.
- Use the SIZEOF, TYPE, and LENGTHOF operators to make the program as flexible as possible if the array size and type should be changed in the future.
- Use the XCHG instruction.
- The array’s elements are: “B”, “A”, “D”, “C”, “F”, “E”, “H”, “G”.
- The array’s elements after running the program should look like: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H.

But I get the following errors:

> error A2006: undefined symbol : arr
>   error A2006: undefined symbol : arr
>   error A2006: undefined symbol : done
>   error A2006: undefined symbol : arr

And this is my code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

arr DWORD B,A,D,C,F,E,H,G ; Array of integers with 8 elements
len DWORD LENGTHOF arr ; The length of the array

.code
main PROC

mov esi,OFFSET arr
mov ecx, LENGTHOF arr/2

reverseArrayOf32bit:
lea edi,[esi+4] ;edi = address of next entry

.next:
mov eax,0
cmp ecx,eax
je .done ; yes, it's done aleady

mov eax,[esi] ;eax = value at start
xchg ebx,[edi] ;ebx = value at end
mov [esi],eax ;Store value from start at end

add esi,8 ;esi = address of next item at start
add edi,8   
dec ecx
j .next

.done:
main ENDP
```

Comment: `The array’s elements are: “B”, “A”, “D”, “C”, “F”, “E”, “H”, “G”.` NO. They are not. You're missing the quotes encapsulating the letters. So change the line to `arr DWORD 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'G'` and the following line to `len DWORD $-arr`. It would probably better to define the letters as BYTEs anyway like in `arr BYTE 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'H', 'G'`.

Comment: You probably got some other errors first, like undefined symbol `A`.